macOS App Notarization Failed - Binary Signature Invalid Error
I'm trying to notarize my macOS app for direct distribution, but I'm encountering an error related to the binary signature. Below is the log output I received.
Error Details:
{
  "logFormatVersion": 1,
  "jobId": "6803b54c-e179-4170-b9e4-1ca99fa547d0",
  "status": "Invalid",
  "statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
  "statusCode": 4000,
  "archiveFilename": "RazorCode.zip",
  "uploadDate": "2024-09-23T11:27:26.799Z",
  "sha256": "54f55d19591fcf2634e223252b43837a7a8e250eae7616775dd2f525fc8ffa47",
  "ticketContents": null,
  "issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "RazorCode.zip/RazorCode.app/Contents/MacOS/RazorCode",
      "message": "The signature of the binary is invalid.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087735",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "RazorCode.zip/RazorCode.app/Contents/MacOS/RazorCode",
      "message": "The signature of the binary is invalid.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087735",
      "architecture": "arm64"
    }
  ]
}

Additional Error with codesign Command:
When I ran the following command to check the code signing, I received the error:
codesign -vvv --deep RazorCode.app/Contents/MacOS/RazorCode

Command Output:
RazorCode.app/Contents/MacOS/RazorCode: unsealed contents present in the root directory of an embedded framework
In subcomponent: /Users/danielkang/Development/razorcode/app/build/macos/Build/Products/Release/RazorCode.app/Contents/Frameworks/FlutterMacOS.framework

What I've tried:

Ensured that I'm using a valid certificate.
Rechecked the code signing steps for both Intel and Apple Silicon (x86_64 and arm64 architectures).
Followed the documentation here: Resolving Common Notarization Issues, but the error persists.

Question:
What could be causing the "The signature of the binary is invalid" error for both architectures? Could this be related to how I'm signing the binary or an issue with the archive itself?
Would appreciate any pointers on how to resolve this issue!
